# What good is the "relative+" operator?

Tags: computer-science, regular-language

I was reading [Composite event specification in active databases: Model and implementation](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.108.2501). In it, a way to specify composite events is described, which is similar to regular expressions. Let me just explain the basics: There are *event histories*. Those are sets of primitive events, each having a unique timestamp (so one can think of them as sequences, but one can use set operations on them). And there are *event expressions*. Those are functions from histories to histories. The expression `E` applied to `h` (`E[h]`) is a subset of `h` where `E` is satisfied. For example, the primitive expression `a` matches a's:
`a[a, b, a, c, b] = a, a` (timestamps implicit).

There is this operator `relative(E, F)`, which is defined thusly:
Let `E_i[h]` be the i:th event occurrences in `E[h]`; let `h_i` be obtained from `h` by deleting all event occurrences whose timestamps are less than or equal to the timestamp of `E_i[h]`. Then `relative(E, F)[h] = union over all i:s F[h_i]`. Less formally, `relative(E, F)` are the event occurrences in `h` at which `F` is satisfied assuming that the history started immediately following some event occurrence in `h` at which `E` takes place. E.g. `relative(a, b)[b, c, a, c, b] = b` (the second b, because there is an a before it).

Now, there is this operator `relative+(E)` which I don't understand the point of. It is defined:
`relative_1(E) = E`
`relative_i(E) = relative(relative_i-1(E), E)`
`relative+(E) = union over all positive i:s relative_i(E)`

How is `relative+(E)` different from just `E`? The way I understand it, `relative(E, E)[h]` is always going to be a subset of `E[h]`, so the union of them is just going to be equal to `E[h]`.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. To see a difference between the results of `E[h]` and `relative+(E)[h]`, `E` needs to be something more complex than just a basic expression matching all events of a certain type. For example: Say we have an event expression `first` that always matches the first event in a history. Then `first[h]` is of course the first element of `h`, while `relative+(first)[h]` is `h` itself, because it's the first of `h`, then the first after the first of `h`, etc.